# Export local Deployd's data into a online server

Tags: mongodb, deployd

I'm using Deployd as an API interface and I have a problem when backing up my Deployd's data and transferring it to an online server.

I have done some research on google and see [this](https://github.com/deployd/deployd/issues/361) issue on GitHub.

as @shawnpk comment I connect to localhost:27017 in Robomongo and that results in this:

```
https://s23.postimg.org/devmppvjf/mongo.png
```

I can't find any sign from the collation from Depolyd in Robomongo.
Any one know how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to point your mongodb execution to the *data* path of your **deployd** project directory. Something like this:
    `mongod --dbpath /path/to/deployd/directory/data/`

Then you can do *mongoexport*